# Select statement returning all ID values for each row

Tags: sql, select, join, duplicates, row

This select statement is returning all values for the timeid for each row.
The joins are joined on the correct unique values.
I have tried inner join/left outer/right outer and full also select distinct to no avail.

```
SELECT
    timed.timeid AS [Time Number], 
    emp.firstname AS [First Name], 
    emp.surname AS [Surame], 
    emp.empid AS [Employee Number], 
    timed.ver AS [Ver],
    timed.tdate AS [Date], 
    shifts.code AS [Code], 
    timed.stime AS [Start], 
    timed.etime AS [End], 
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, timed.stime, timed.etime) AS [Hours]
FROM 
    emp 
    INNER JOIN timed ON emp.divid = timed.divid
    INNER JOIN shifts ON timed.shiftid = shifts.shiftid     

Time Number First Name  Surame  Employee Number Ver     Date    Code      Start        End     Hours
OPS93041        C        BLOGS     G100         142 30/04/2013  Nts     19:00:00    06:00:00    11
OPS93041        L        SMITH     I101         142 30/04/2013  Nts     19:00:00    06:00:00    11
OPS93041        M        WALKER    M115         142 30/04/2013  Nts     19:00:00    06:00:00    11
OPS93041        P        DJANGO    P965         142 30/04/2013  Nts     19:00:00    06:00:00    11
```

As the small example of the results above show it is adding the timeid to all of the results, and also possibly the other values other than the ones from the emp table.

Desired Output would be something like.

```
Time Number First Name  Surame  Employee Number Ver     Date    Code      Start        End     Hours
OPS93041        C        BLOGS     G100         142 30/04/2013  Nts     19:00:00    06:00:00    11
JDY73592        L        SMITH     I101         142 24/03/2013  Nts     11:00:00    17:00:00    6
QJA74057        M        WALKER    M115         188 08/07/2013  Nts     08:00:00    15:00:00    7
PDG03845        P        DJANGO    P965         125 19/01/2013  Nts     22:00:00    03:00:00    5
```

Comment: what is wrong in it? please provide table structure in sqlfiddle

Comment: added results table and more of an explanation above

Comment: add desired output you need

Comment: There is nothing wrong in this query. if you still doubt than put your three table with data. and also put exact desired output.

Comment: Added desired outcome, there should only be 1 or 2 time numbers that are the same, but at the minute it is giving every single time number to every single row and creating lots of duplicate data.

Comment: Table structure and relations is key here, I suspect that you are missing an additional JOIN condition. My guess based on the fact that you expect a unique record in `Timed` for each employee that the missing condition is `emp.empID = timed.empID`, however this is pure speculation until I can see your table structure...

Comment: @Matt : please provide table structure and table data for deeply understand your question

Comment: @GarethD Thank you! this comment got me thinking of how i needed to link these in a different way, the ID's i used to join the tables were not unique thus causing the duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by grouping the data by employee so the times were relevant to the employee line rather than the shift number